# Set default entity ID variable for HATEOAS spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a HATEOAS Spring rest API that connects to a mysql database. I have no control over the database schema and it changes periodically so I am periodically generating the entity classes and updating the service.

I have three files per route. A generated entity class, a controller and a repository file that uses the `PagingAndSortingRepository` class to automatically serve my entities without much configuration.

Entity class

```
    package hello.models;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.Objects;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "animals", schema = "xyz123", catalog = "")
    public class AnimalsEntity {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String description;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 80)
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 255)
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            RoleEntity that = (RoleEntity) o;
            return Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                    Objects.equals(name, that.name) &&
                    Objects.equals(description, that.description);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {

            return Objects.hash(id, name, description);
        }
    }
```

Repository class

```
    package hello.repositories;

    @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "animals", path = "animals")
    public interface AnimalsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AnimalEntity, String> {

        // Allows /animal/cheetah for example.
        AnimalEntity findByName(String name);

        // Prevents POST /element and PATCH /element/:id
        @Override
        @RestResource(exported = false)
        public AnimalEntity save(AnimalEntity s);

        // Prevents DELETE /element/:id
        @Override
        @RestResource(exported = false)
        public void delete(AnimalEntity t);
    }
```

Controller class

```
    package hello.controllers;

    import hello.models.AnimalsEntity; 
    import hello.repositories.AnimalsRepository; 
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
    import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    import java.util.List;


    @RepositoryRestController
    @RequestMapping("/animals")
    class PrinterController {

        @Autowired
        private AnimalsRepository animalsRepo;

        @RequestMapping("/{name}")
        public @ResponseBody
        List<AnimalsEntity> findAnimal(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
            return animalsRepo.findByName(name);
        }

    }
```

I want my HATEOAS API to serve things with the pagination/sorting options. They currently serves responses like..

```
    {
      "links" : [ {
        "rel" : "first",
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/animals?page=0&size=20",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
      }, {
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/animals{?page,size,sort}",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
      }, {
        "rel" : "next",
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/animals?page=1&size=20",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
      }, {
        "rel" : "last",
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/animals?page=252&size=20",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
      }, {
        "rel" : "profile",
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/animals",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
      }, {
        "rel" : "search",
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/animals/search",
        "hreflang" : null,
        "media" : null,
        "title" : null,
        "type" : null,
        "deprecation" : null
      } ],
      "content" : [ {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "cheetah",
        "description": "xyz
        ]
      },{
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "tortise",
        "description": "xyz
        ]
      }],
      "page" : {
        "size" : 20,
        "totalElements" : 5049,
        "totalPages" : 253,
        "number" : 0
      }
    }
```

This is awesome. But I need my javascript applications to access the rest api like (GET) `/animals/cheetah`.

Normally I would change the schema and set `@Id` on the name property in the entity class but I cannot do that in this instance. I cant change the database schema and eventually I want to dynamically generate these entity classes to allow for easy schema changes.

I've figured out that I can override the endpoint and serve it manually but I lose the pagination/HATEOAS formatting.

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "cheetah",
        "description": "xyz"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "tortise",
        "description": "xyz"
      }
    ]
```

How do I accomplish the @Id change without losing the JSON format or changing the entity class?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_customizing_item_resource_uris

You can map other fields as the default lookup.